# getOrElse default to different type

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi

Having an issue where I simply want to return an empty string from this `JsValue` instead of returning a 0 if no value is found. Basically I want what follows:

```
var cellValue = (x \ "name" \ "date").asOpt[Float].getOrElse("")
```

I am doing this mainly because I am using Apache POI to build an Excel sheet and don't want zeros as a default when there wouldn't be any data. But to use `.setCellValue(cellValue)` it can't be an `Any` type, which is what this is giving me.

I've tried

```
var cellValue = (x \ "name" \ "date").asOpt[Float].getOrElse(0)
if(cellValue == 0) {
   cellValue = ""
}
cell.setCellValue(cellValue)
```

but that gave me issues with changing `cellValue` to `String` type. Also tried this

```
var cellValue = (x \ "name" \ "date").asOpt[Float].getOrElse(0)
if(cellValue == 0) {
   cell.setCellValue("")
} else cell.setCellValue(cellValue)
```

but this gave me an issue that I am overloading method `.setCellValue` with alternatives. I am used to this working as I come from a Java background, not sure why that would fail.

Am still getting the hang of Scala so please bear with me if there is a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use `map` to transform the `Option[Float]` to an `Option[String]` before calling `getOrElse`:

```
val cellValue = (x \ "name" \ "date").asOpt[Float]
                                     .map(_.toString)
                                     .getOrElse("")
```

The above returns a `String`.

```
cell.setValue(cellValue)
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I needed! I had also tried `(x \ "name" \ "date").asOpt[Float].getOrElse[String]("")` but it wasn't working for me either. This works though!